# Plotting 2darray with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

```
a = np.arange(1,10).reshape((3,3))

plt.plot(a[0],a[1:])
```

Why am I getting: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension error?

Comment: Because they have different shapes. Try `plt.plot(a[0],a[1])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve.
Clearly, your dimensions do not fit between the x- and y-axis.
You can just transpose `a[1:]` to plot both lines along the axis defined by `a[0]` as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(1,10).reshape((3,3))
print("Shape of a: " + str(a.shape)) # Shape of a: (3, 3)
print("Shape of a[0]: " + str(a[0].shape)) # Shape of a[0]: (3,)
print("Shape of a[1:]: " + str(a[1:].shape)) # Shape of a[1:]: (2, 3)
print("Shape of a[1:].T: " + str(a[1:].T.shape)) # Shape of a[1:].T: (3, 2)
plt.plot(a[0],a[1:].T)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I saw the documenation https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot

Comment: I saw the documenation https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot
and i am wondering how i can achieve plt.plot(a[0],a[1:]). Can you give an example of such 2d array ?